# i want to save the result of the'for-loop' as text file in python

Tags: python, for-loop, save, text-files

I used for-loop.
i want to save the result of the'for-loop' as text file. how can i do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H282d.png)

Comment: Please post the code into the question, not linked as an image.

Comment: Are you talking about saving row by row in the for loop? Or saving the result of the for loop? Please be more clear and provide your code.

Comment: Here is a tutorial that ought to help you: https://programminghistorian.org/lessons/working-with-text-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line as

```
print(how_can_i_do[h*a:h*(a+1)], file=f, end='\n')
```

After loop, you also have to close all the file streams.